# adding row from separate thread

Tags: c#, datagridview, bindinglist

I have a dataGridView and a list of custom class. After I bind the list to dataGridView using .dataSource property. When I try to add new row from a thread to the list, I get cross-threading Exception. How can I add a row from a separate thread?

I tried the following solution: http://c-sharp-programming.blogspot.com/2008/07/cross-thread-operation-not-valid.html

but I can't access updateLabelText method from my other classes.. Any suggestions? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

BackgroundWorkers are good for this kind of thing - they can update lists and things by reporting "progress" to the GUI thread.

But your cross-class issue may be a bit different and you may need to provide a delegate called `StatusUpdate` or some-such to allow the classes to remain independent of one another (and yet still report on status).

Hope that helps. Your question's kinda vague!!